# Can't find VS2008 installdir registry in Windows 7 x64

Tags: visual-studio-2008, registry

I'm currently writing a building script that needs the installdir registry key for visual studio 2008 to find where the devenv is. In windows vista, the registry key used to be in local machine\software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\installdir, but in windows 7 x64, it seemed to be not found. I tried, but failed to find it in other directories as well.

Did anyone else have this problem?

Comment: yes, I'm running x64 RTM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows x64 all 32 bit (VisualStudio is one of them) proceess that write to `(HKLM | HKCU)\SOFTWARE` registry path are redriected to `(HKLM | HKCU)\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` path, look for it under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0`

Comment: Damn, 64bit is causing some really irritating nuisances.